# Typescript Union Types: Type Names as object members

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to extract the names of types so I can use them as Keys in a Type definition?

```
type O1 = {…}
type O2 = {…}
type O3 = {…}
type Item = O1 | O2 | O3;

type ItemCalculator = {
  [key: string]: Function
} // how can I enforce key to be either "O1" or "O2" or "O3"
```

Comment: `O1`,  `O2`, `O3` are strings ? Because keys to an object can only be string numbers or symbols. If you want to use object as keys you need a `Map`

Comment: Hi Titian, no unfortunately not, they are objects.  Only idea I came up with so far, was storing the Object name inside the object itself, say: `O3 = {type: "O3", …}` but this seems a bit redundant, as I want the type information primarily while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly do something like this

```
type ItemCalculator = {
  [key: Item]: Function
}
```

because you will end up with an exception ["An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead"](https://typescript.tv/error-ts/includes/ts1337)

But you can use [mapped object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as suggested.

In a simplified example:

```js
type Item = "O1" | "O2" | "O3";

type ItemCalculator = {
  [I in Item]: Function;
};

const itemCalculator: ItemCalculator = {
  O1: () => {}, // OK
  O2: () => {}, // OK
  O3: () => {}, // OK
  O4: () => {}, // typescript error ts(2322)
};
```

To answer the comment of @michael

> Any chance I can infer these strings dynamically? Currently I a have
> some automatically generated definitions from a backend

Yes. Using [Generic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types). But you will need to know in advance what type of object you will received.

e.g

```
type ItemCalculator<Type> = {
  [T in keyof Type]: Function;
};

type ApiResponse = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
};

const itemCalculator: ItemCalculator<ApiResponse> = {
  name: (item: ApiResponse) => item.name,
  id: (item: ApiResponse) => item.id,
};
```

Comment: Any chance I can infer these strings dynamically? Currently I a have some automatically generated definitions from a backend (I don't control), from there I take only a subset of Types (those that have certain properties in their object structur) which I'd like to feed to my calculator then.

Comment: Wow thank you very much! I still have a lot to learn but this is a great starting point!